# How to set router correctly in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

When I run server through Express I have caught error like described below.

When I access url below,

`https://5a75307007e3415f9aaca9d3052ed731.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/_static/login_form/views/login`

The error below is displayed.

`The file '/login_form/views/login' could not be found. Are you sure it is in your environment?`

My current work is like below,

Are there any weird point?

Thanks

```
login_form/views $ ls
login.html  main.css  signup.html
```

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login.html');
});

app.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
  res.render('signup.html');
});



app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('server is running!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rendering the file is used by the view engine for example EJS, Pug etc

So if you want to use html file other then the view engine you have to use `sendFile()`

like this

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/login.html'));
});
```